# Why is this page's body center-aligned?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am putting together a new site from an existing site and copying over some of the html and css.  I don't really understand why the body is center-aligned here: http://www.problemio.com/auth/forgot_password.php

Any idea what is doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: That's one doctype I've never seen before: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `body {text-align: center}` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheet being served from Yahoo has `body { text-align: center; }` in it. You can just put `body { text-align: left; }` in yours to counter it.